# Finding a function from given function and equation

Tags: calculus

A car with mass $m=1.5$ is moving along a straight line. Distance covered is described by $s(t)=t^3+t$ where $t>0$

(a) Kinetic energy $E$ is given by $E=$$mv^2\over 2$ where v is the car speed.

(b) Find kinetic energy at time $t=10$

(c) What distance is covered by time $t=7$?

(d) Find approximate value of time $t$ when the speed is $25$

(e) Find a function that describes the acceleration

(f) Find the acceleration at $t=6$

(g) Find the time when the acceleration is $18$

My answers.

(a) $Velocity(v)=s'(t)$

$v(t)={d\over dt}(t^3+t)=3t^2+1$

Kinetic energy $E={1.5(3t^2+1)^2\over 2}$

(b) ${1.5(3\cdot10^2+1)^2\over 2}$=67,950.75

(c) $s(t)=7^3+7=350$

(d) $25=3t^2+1$

$=2.83$

(e) I'm stuck from this point down. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the function for acceleration, you need to differentiate v(t)

$a(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(3t^{2}+1)$

$a(t) = 6t$

So for f)

$a(t) = 6(6) = 36m/s^{2}$

And for g)

$18 = 6*t$

$t=3s$